# Change connection string on runing azure app service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have been created an asp.net web api with a sql server running on MS SQL server. I have uploaded the sql database to azure, then I have added the asp.net web api to azure too. I then edited the connection string (find it below) inside the web.api file to point to the sql server database currently on azure. I have not been added to access the database through the web api

I have tried accessing the sql database using a local client and I am able to access the database. I havee also tried accessing the web api and I have been able to load some pages.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=floshopadmin;Initial Catalog=FloShop;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I don't see anything *"below"*.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=floshopadmin;Initial Catalog=FloShop;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is using "Integrated Security".

Most likely your database was setup to allow access to your Windows User account.
The ASP.NET process in Azure isn't going to be running under that account.

Create a new User on the database and use the credentials from that user to connect instead of "Integrated Security".

Comment: what about the  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"?

Comment: That part's fine.

Comment: I have updated the web.config file and restarted the app service but the connection string is still like 
    ConnectionString = data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
    ProviderName = System.Data.SqlClient
when i view the project app service properties.

Comment: There are a few different ways that you can put your database in Azure and the connection string that you need to use depends largely on that.

Are you running a virtual machine with Sql Server running on it?
Are you using "Azure Sql"?
Is your database just a file that lives on a Virtual Machine shared by your web server?

Comment: i am running azure sql

Comment: Then since you're using Azure Sql, your connection string format will be this:

Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;

(see https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/)

Chuck that in your web.config and see what happens.

Also, I recommend that you make sure that your AppService and Database Server are in the same region. Otherwise, you'll run into performance issues.